# How would one create a method that has parameters of a char array and a char that finds a specific character in the array and returns the index

Tags: java, arrays, methods

```
import java.io.*;
import java.math.*;
import java.security.*;
import java.text.*;
import java.util.*;
import java.util.concurrent.*;
import java.util.regex.*;


class Result {

/*
 * Complete the 'search' function below.
 *
 * The function is expected to return an INTEGER.
 * The function accepts following parameters:
 *  1. CHARACTER_ARRAY myList
 *  2. CHARACTER letter
 */

public static int search(char[] myList, char letter) {

     for(int i = 0; i < myList.length; i++){
        if(myList[i] == (letter)){
   
 }



 }
 return....

}
}
```

How would I approach this question not understanding how you would find a specific char in an array of chars....What would I return so that If the char isn't found it returns -1.

What would one input to the array and char parameter?

Answer (score 0):

I added a main method so that I can made the char array and the char letter. All you had to do was in the if statement, return the index, which is i. Then, outside of the for loop, if the letter was never found, then return -1. The "return -1" will only be reached if i is not returned.

```
public class Result {
   public static int search(char[] myList, char letter) {
   
        for(int i = 0; i < myList.length; i++){
           if(myList[i] == (letter)){
                return i;
           }
        }
      return -1;
   }
   
   public static void main(String[] args){
      char[] myList = {'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h'};
      char letter = 'h';
      int index = search(myList, letter);
      System.out.println(index);
   }
}
```